# LDO performance improvement

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, ldo

[image]I'm using NCP1117ST50T3G by Onsemi and it is connected 12 V comes from a power AC to DC module. How can I improve LDO's performance?

Output is oscillating respect to noise in the input. You can refer attached image for reference. [image]

I'm new to this. So all suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There is no circuit shown so how to improve an unknown circuit can't be answered.

Comment: You seem to be using a 5ns time base. It's hard to measure but the frequency of your noise seems to be around 150MHz. First: this is way beyond what an LDO can filter out. Second: please show with a phot how you're measuring. At those frequncies there is a decent probability that you're getting this noise via a ground loop. Third: when measuring noise use AC coupling on the Scope (that's what that mode is for)

Comment: Like kruemi said, no oscilloscope probe with wire. Try to use the spring for gnd. And even if it was noise on the line: would be little bit more than 6%. We want to get rid of every spike yes, but it’s not even that bad.

Comment: @kruemi I'm measuring CH1 across +12V and GND and CH2 across 5V out and GND.

Comment: @Justme Updated.

Comment: Now we don't know what caps those are. Does the output cap fill the required capacitance and ESR ratings at the rated 5V voltage? Are the caps near the regulator or far away? Are you sure you are actually measuring the LDO instead of just the noise caused by the switching regulator which can be seen everywhere with wrong measuring techniques?

Comment: @SarathK Why are you even considering an LDO when going from 12 V to 5 V? Seriously? These are totally turned inside out in order to help reduce the voltage drop across them and you lose [control loop stability](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt194/slyt194.pdf?ts=1669602517157&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) from the traditional linear regulator in the process. Since you are burning off 7 V of overhead already, there's more than enough for any more-stable linear circuit. Why an LDO??? Just because?

Comment: @jonk This 5V is connected to a touch sensing IC, for its application LDO is recommended.

Comment: @Justme As per datasheet we are using tantalum capacitor. And capacitors are nearby LDO regulator.

Comment: @SarathK I'd very much like to see that 'recommendation' in detail. My guess is that it is being misinterpreted/misapplied. Just my thought for now.

Comment: @jonk You can refer datasheet of AT42QT1110 by Microchip.

Comment: I’m curious: did the measured result change? Like with other probing technique?

Comment: @RemyHx No. It remains same.

Comment: @SarathK Today I saw this article, maybe interesting because of your question: https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/articles/1068-avoid-these-two-artifacts-when-measuring-smps-power-rails